# Grouping of the results in AutoSuggestBox UWP

Tags: grouping, autosuggest, uwp

When using SearchBox in Windows 8.1, on *SuggestionsRequested* event there is ability to separate results if they can be grouped with the help of *AppendSearchSeparator*.
But I can't find something similar for grouping in AutoSuggestBox.
How can grouping of search(suggestion) results be implemented/applied in **AutoSuggestBox** for UWP ?

Answer (score 1):

It is strange, in MSDN it says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn301949.aspx)

> SearchBox is no longer available for use as of Windows 10. Instead, use AutoSuggestBox.

So I tried to use a AutoSuggestBox in a UWP app, as it said here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn919949.aspx), there should be a event: onsuggestionsrequested, but in XAML, I didn't find it either.

So, I tried to find a new event in which the SuggestionsRequested event can be used, but I failed.

Finally, I downloaded a sample code of a Windows 8.1 SerachBox here(https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SearchBox-control-sample-0f64f94d), and ported it to a UWP app, the result is, the SearchBox can still be used in a UWP app.

Maybe there is a event of AutoSuggestBox for this, I just didn't find it. This is a good question I think.